# How does SBT resolve the default scope for a given key?

Tags: sbt

I'd like to see the `inspect tree` invoked when I run, for example `rpm:packageBin'. However,

`(web238/Package-RPM) root: inspect tree rpm:packageBin
[info]  = 
(web238/Package-RPM) root: inspect rpm:packageBin
[info] No entry for key.
[info] Description:
[info]  Produces a main artifact, such as a binary jar.
[info] Delegates:
[info]  root/rpm:packageBin
[info]  root/*:packageBin
[info]  {.}/rpm:packageBin
[info]  {.}/*:packageBin
[info]  */rpm:packageBin
[info]  */*:packageBin
[info] Related:
[info]  myproject-common/compile:packageBin
[info]  myproject-checkout/compile:packageBin
[info]  myproject-website/debian:packageBin
[info]  myproject-search/compile:packageBin
[info]  myproject-basket/compile:packageBin
[info]  myproject-common-cassandra/test:packageBin
[info]  myproject-website/windows:packageBin
[info]  myproject-website/rpm:packageBin
[info]  root/test:packageBin
[info]  myproject-basket/test:packageBin`

Is there an easy way to find out what the actual key is that is invoked when I call `rpm:packageBin`?

Comment: I would say that `inspect tree` shows an actual tree. What does `inspect actual rpm:packageBin` says? Did you modify `packageBin in Rpm` in any way?

Comment: `inspect actual rpm:packageBin` produces the same output as `inspect rpm:packageBin` above. I don't think we modified `packageBin in Rpm`

Comment: Can you add your build definition. PS. block of code on SO can be defined by using an indentation instead of triple backticks.